# ¿Cómo hago una @GETMapping por nombre Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman, swagger

Estoy empezando con Java + Spring Boot, y ya eh realizado post, put, get, delete y patch, todo a nivel de backEnd por lo cual las pruebas lo hago en postman o swagger.

Estoy trabajando con capas y tengo:

- Controlador
- Entity
- Repository
- Service

Y hago lo siguiente:

1. En el controlador hago una inyección del servicio que desee y mando mi solicitud por ejemplo

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "cliente", produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
public class ClienteController {
    @Autowired
    private ClienteServices clienteServices;
    

    @GetMapping("/selectAllCliente")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ClienteEntity>> selectAll(){
        return clienteServices.selectAll();
    }
}
```

2. En el servicio inyecto el repositorio y hago mi consulta, por ejemplo:

```
@Service
public class ClienteServices {
    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;
    
    
    public ResponseEntity<List<ClienteEntity>> selectAll(){
        try {
            List<ClienteEntity> lista = clienteRepository.findAll();
            if (!lista.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<ClienteEntity>>(lista,HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<ClienteEntity>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<ClienteEntity>>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Y me gustaría saber como hace un **@GetMaping pero por nombre** debido que no encuentro nada similar con que guiarme.

Comment: Mi respuesta: fue hacer un query dentro del repository y enviar el nombre con @RequestParam

Comment: ¿Cuál es la parte que te tiene bloqueado? En el controller necesitas declarar request params, en el repository sólo has de declarar el método, ya que Spring es capaz de entender por el nombre el tipo de filtro que quieres aplicar.

Comment: Documentación de spring sobre los repositorios: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

Primero en el `ClientRepository` hay que implementar `findByNombre`
En el servicio implementar como recuperar client por nombre básicamente es esto `repository.findByNombre(String nombre)`
En el controlador haz `@getMapping("/{nombre}")` y
en el método del controlador pon un parámetro con `@PathVariable String nombre`.

Answer (score 0):

Se haría de la siguiente forma. Primero debemos de indicar en el dao una consulta que busque por usuario.

```
@Query(value="select c from #{#entityName} c where c.username = ?1")
public Usuario findByUsuername(@Param("username") String username) throws Exception;
```

Luego en la interfaz del servicio lo implementas:

```
public Usuario findByUsuername(String username) throws Exception;
```

Implementamos el método en el sercioImpl.Java

```
Inyectamos el dao

@Autowired
private IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;

@Override
public Usuario findByUsuername(String username) throws Exception {
return usuarioDao.findByUsername(username);
}
```

Luego en controlador debes de pasar el método a la vista.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buscar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String buscarUsu(@Param(value = "username") String username, Model model) throws Exception{
try {
model.addAttribute("titulo", "Buscar usuario");
model.addAttribute("usuarios", clienteService. findByUsuername(username));
}catch(Exception e){
throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
}
return "buscar";
}
```

Por último implementas la vista o de recojas el nombre a buscar dentro de un input:

```
<form th:action="@{/buscar}" th:object="${usuario}" method="get">
<div class="form-group row py-2">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" class="form-control" th:errorsClass="'form-control alert-danger'" />
                
    </div>
</div>
```

Creo que con esto podrías implementarlo en tu proyecto. Disculpa si hay algún error pero lo he hecho desde la tablet.

Un saludo.